# Behavior of eigenvalues of certain matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetry

I am trying to analyze the behavior of the 2 highest eigenvalues of matrices of this form : 
Symmetric $n*n$ matrices that contains only : $1/k$ (for fixed k), -1,1 and 0. My hope is to find some asymptotic bounds or some way to approximate the eigenvalues.

If that's unclear please let me know and I'll edit it.

Thanks

Comment: do you have data for small vales of $n?$

Comment: Nope. I'll try to generate some